# Full privileges on .command file, but it says I don't have appropriate privileges

Tags: macos, terminal, script

I have a command that I regularly need to run in the Terminal (for application code signing). Normally I launch the Terminal, press the up arrow until I reach the command I want, and then hit enter.

I've decided that a more sustainable solution might be to create a file I can just double-click to run the Terminal command. In my searches, I discovered that I could create a text file with the `.command` extension which contains the command that I want to run.

However, when I double-click on this file, the Terminal opens and I get the following error:

> The file “Sign Code.command” could not be executed because you do not
> have appropriate access privileges.
>
> To view or change access
> privileges, select the file in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

The problem is that when I go to the Get Info wind as directed and look at my Permissions, it says that my user has read-write access (the only other option is read). So in other words, I have the highest permissions, but still can't open this file.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to set 'execute' on the file for it to allow you to run it:

```
chmod u+x /path/to/file.command
```

<sup>`u` is the owner of the file, `+x` adds 'execute', so `u+x` gives the owner of the file the ability to execute it</sup>

…then you can run it in the future by double-clicking it.

PS: If you are not used to using shells, open Terminal, type `chmod u+x` followed by space, drag&drop the command file into the Terminal window and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: So the error message is wrong and I can't fix the permissions by going to the Get Info window like it says? I don't have a problem with using the Terminal to fix it, I'm just surprised that the message might tell me to do something wrong.

Comment: @Thunderforge Indeed, it's wrong, as far as I know :) I'm pretty sure Finder can't do it — you have to do it using Terminal or other script.

Comment: Explain this to somebody with no experience in Terminal. When I type that verbatim, it says file.command does not exist. I tried using the actual name of the .command file I’m trying to double click on to run and still no luck. Typed out the actual file path with each folder separated by a forward slash and starting from Macintosh HD and that still doesn’t work.

Comment: @rick I've added an explanation to the answer.