# Howto run a Terminal command using shortcut or a button

Tags: terminal, command-line

I always have the problem in my dock, where the download bar just stops and stays froze. I know you can do a `killall -KILL Dock` and it will fix the issue.

Is there a way to click a button or do a keyboard-shortcut that runs this Terminal command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this, here are 2.

#### First method: Create a quick script that runs after a double-click.

Create a text file, named `myScript.command`. The '.command' postfix will let Finder know to run it on opening.

Add the following as plain text:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall -KILL Dock
```

Now the script exists but needs to be executable. To do this you need to do a `chmod`.

```
chmod 755 myScript.command
```

Running `myScript.command` will open a Terminal window and run the command. The first line, hashbang, will let your computer know to use bash for the following script. You can set the preferences in `Terminal.app` to close the terminal window after a clean exit.

#### Second method: Create a 'Service' and bind a keystroke to that service.

Create and install the service:

1. Open Automator
2. New Document -> Service
3. Add the 'Run Shell Script' module and insert your code `killall -KILL Dock`
4. Set the 'Service receives `no input`', save and quit.
5. Install your newly created service by opening it in Finder and choose 'Install'.

Attach a keystroke to this service:

6. Open 'System preferences' -> 'Keyboard' -> 'Keyboard shortcuts' -> 'Services'
7. Find the 'Kill Dock' service and attach a keystroke to it.

[image: Automator - Run Shell Script]

Comment: If I were to add another command to the myscript.command would I just write the other command on the bottom like if I want it to KILL finder and dock.

Comment: Added the fix for your problem.

Comment: @Ilya See [Full privileges on .command file, but it says I don't have appropriate privileges](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113974/full-privileges-on-command-file-but-it-says-i-dont-have-appropriate-privilege), Gatekeeper isn't the problem here.

Comment: @grgarside, thnx. I updated the answer. So used to this that I forgot.

Comment: So I used automator and did everything exactly but whenever I enable the service through Keyboard Commands it doesnt work but whenever I run it in Automator it works and restarts my dock. This it the command I set (⌃⌥⌘D). See it works fine in Automator > http://i.imgur.com/CEYnmqK.png

Comment: @CousinCocaine ^

Comment: @IlyaVorobyev, does your Service exist in the System? You can check this by pressing 'Safari -> Services -> Kill Dock' (http://imgur.com/7eGVleP)

Comment: @CousinCocaine Ohh it only works whenever I have text selected. How can I do it so I can hit the command anywhere?

Comment: @IlyaVorobyev I made this in a rush, and now it keeps comming back with small errors. Sorry. In Automator set the 'Service receives no input'. I fixed this in the screenshot and the text.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot I get it now :D I'm just sort of new to this. I recently made the change to mac and haven't gotten to deep into it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a shortcut to run an applescript which runs the terminal command. [here](https://superuser.com/questions/815162/how-can-i-run-an-applescript-from-my-mac-with-a-shortcut-without-using-3rd-part) is a question on superuser with the first answer explaining how to make a shortcut to an applescript.

## How to Make a Shortcut to Applescript in Automator

Make a new service and add your applescript
[image: alt]

[image: alt]
Make a keyboard shortcut using system preferences

Keyboard shortcuts will work across applications.

---

Made by rahul_send89 from Super User

Then you can do this as the applescript to the Automator input (As shown on the screenshot):

```
do shell script "sudo killall -KILL Dock" with administrator privileges
```

I put it in sudo (admin) just in case it would require.

Or without admin:

```
do shell script "killall -KILL Dock" with user privileges
```

Comment: Please do not use links, if the link dies your answer will have no value.

Comment: Ok, I will edit question to incl. the contents of the link, and add credit to the owner