# .command The file could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges

Tags: terminal, mac, command-line, bash, permission

I am trying to execute a terminal command by just double clicking a .command file. But I am getting this error.

> The file “myfile.command” could not be executed because you do not
>   have appropriate access privileges. To view or change access
>   privileges, select the file in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.

I have looked at this answer but it doesn't work: [Full privileges on .command file, but it says I don't have appropriate privileges](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113974/full-privileges-on-command-file-but-it-says-i-dont-have-appropriate-privilege)

I tried all of these:

```
sudo chmod u+x /path/to/myfile.command
chmod u+x /path/to/myfile.command
chmod u+x docker start sql_server_demo
sudo chmod a+x /path/to/myfile.command
chmod a+x /path/to/myfile.command
chmod a+x docker start sql_server_demo
```

In `myfile.command` I would have this:

```
docker start sql_server_demo
```

Nothing seems to be working. And when I go to `Users and Groups` then my `current user` does have `Admin` rights. So I really don't understand why I am getting this error. Does the `myfile.command`'s location matter?

`ls -la: -rw-r--r--@  1 (myname)  staff     68 Aug 16 11:20 myfile.command`

`file: myfile.command: ASCII text, with no line terminators`

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to Ask Different. Can you add the output of these commands to your question: `ls -la /path/to/my_file.command` and `file /path/to/my_file.command` ?

Comment: @jaume I added both of those, does that help?

Comment: It looks like command `chmod u+x /path/to/myfile.command` didn't properly set the executable bit, the permission bits should read `-rwxr--r--@`, the `x` is missing. I can't say why you couldn't set the correct mode, you may want to share the directory where the file is located, that could help find an explanation. As a workaround, could you add the line `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the file, test if double-clicking the file works and report back?

Comment: @jaume I don't really know what happened but since today everything is working fine. I can double click a file and it works. I have no idea what changed though (I was about to test your last comment)

Comment: Hi Paul, great it's working. Could it be that the file is now executable (`rwx-r--r--`)?